# Чому визна́чник, а не ви́значник чи визначни́к?

Tags: фонетика, наголос

Чому у слові визначник наголос повинен падати на „а“ згідно із чинними словниками, а не на „и“?

У словниках це слово появляється із 1928 року [r2u.org.ua](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on), але всюди наголос вказаний на букву „а“, тобто визна́чник. Натомість у середовищі галицьких математиків (а також, либонь, у решти краях) побутує версія з наголосом на букву и, тобто визначни́к, або інколи кажуть ви́значник. Але вельми рідко визна́чник. Чи наявне якесь правило або міркування, що обґрунтовують наголошування букви а у тому слові?

Comment: Хм, ми теж, здається, вимовляли «визначни́к», хоч явно не галицькі.

Comment: @Sasha, я за усю Україну не можу стверджувати. Проте ваше зауваження свідчить, що невідповідний літературним нормам наголос на и у такому простому слові побутує не лише в Галичині. Відредагував своє питання.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Прикметник «визначний»

[«Російсько-український словник» А. Кримського та С. Єфремова (1924–1933)](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&dicts=1) та [«Російсько-український словник» О. Ізюмова (1930)](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&dicts=2) подають прикметник «визначний» із наголосом, що залежить від значення:

1. «Визначни́й» — той, що виділяється або важливий (видатний, значний);
2. «Визна́чний» — той, який який можна визначити/обчислити.

Але в [одинадцятитомному тлумачному «Словнику української мови» (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/vyznachnyj) обидва значення вже мають однаковий наголос:

> визначни́й

Сучасні словники ([1](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&dicts=2), [2](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&dicts=4), [3](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&dicts=5)) часто знов фіксують розрізнення значень прикметника за наголосом — але я не вважаю вже це надважливим. Процес злиття вимови «визначни́й» і «визна́чний» **почався**, і хоча багато хто ще бачить різницю, дехто її вже не відчуває.

### Іменник «визначник»

Можливо, іменник «визначник», що, очевидно, походить від 2-го значення прикметника, а не 1-го, успадкував наголос 2-го значення і, відповідно, спочатку був мав наголос на «а».

Але з тенденцією часткової втрати різниці між «визначни́й» і «визна́чний» і подекуди пересування наголосу в обох значеннях на «и», він теж набрав тенденцію бути наголошеним на «и». Хоча [11-томний](http://sum.in.ua/s/vyznachnyk) і [«Орфоепічний словник» Погрібного (1984)](http://padaread.com/?book=84816&pg=80) все ще наголошують його по-старому, сучасні словники ([1](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&dicts=2), [2](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&dicts=4), [3](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&dicts=5)) вже фіксують саме «**визначни́к**».

### Висновок

Я би сприймав «визна́чник» радше як застарілу норму; сучасну — як «визначни́к».

З іншого боку, наголоси — то дуже гнучка штука. І варіююча за регіонами/діалектами; навіть саме розрізнення/нерозрізнення значень може розбігатися за регіонами/діалектами. Тому я б не вважав інші варіанти «неправильними».

Comment: Взагалі-то, «визна́чний» у значенні „той, який який можна визначити/обчислити“ я ніколи не зустрічав у математичних текстах. Для цього більше пасує слово „визначуваний“.  
У вказаних вами словниками одним із авторів є математик Мейнарович Євген. Він звісно позначив наголос на и, бо саме так кажуть математики. Крім цих словників, такий же наголос на „и“ я знайшов лише у Перехреста В. І. Російсько - українському словнику з математики, фізики та  інформатики. У всіх інших (навіть у тій же вікіпедії) наголос на „а“.
@Sasha, дякую за всеосяжну відповідь.

Comment: @АндрійБандура, «взагалі-то, „визна́чний“ у значенні „той, який який можна визначити/обчислити“ я ніколи не зустрічав у математичних текстах» — ну але, тим не менш, таке слово є/було. «Для цього більше пасує слово „визначуваний“» — «[визначуваний](http://sum.in.ua/s/vyznachuvanyj)», мені здається, зазвичай має трішки інший відтінок значення — це той, який зараз визначають, а не той, який взагалі можна визначити (хоч можу помилятися). За посилання на «Російсько-український словник з математики, фізики та інформатики» В. Перехреста (2008) дякую (як я зрозумів, він теж на «визначни́к»).

Comment: @АндрійБандура, а хтось, окрім Вікіпедії (як, звісно, сама не аргумент), зараз ставить наголос «визна́чник»?

Comment: математики вельми рідко вживають „визна́чник“, натомість мовники люблять так виправляти їх, бо, мовляв, такий наголос зазначений у словниках української мови. Перелічувати їх звісно немає сенсу. Лишень зазначу, що навіть у двох Російсько-українських математичних словниках Карачуна та Гудименка (виданих у 90-их)  або у книжці Складні випадки наголошування (автор Головащук) також вказано визна́чник. Тому це протиріччя мене постійно бентежило. Щоправда, визначник також біологічний термін. Можливо, біологи вживають більше визна́чник, ніж визначни́к.

Comment: @АндрійБандура, хм, ну тоді виходить, що я неправий. Бо мені здавалося, що це просто запізнілий рух навздогін змінам наголосу у прикметнику. І всі сучасні словники, що мені трапилися (до того, як Ви навели ці два: Карачун і Головащук), казали «визначни́к».

Comment: навпаки ви праві, бо згадані вами словники Мейнаровича вийшли недавно у 2010 році, тобто найновіші. Адже словник Карачуна вийшов у 1995, друге видання словника Гудименка у 1990 році (а перше ще у 1960 році), словник Головащука Складні випадки наголошення у 1995 році. 
Словник Перехреста з наголосом на „и“ також вийшов у 2008 році. Просто наголоси змінили лише у математичних словниках, дійсно наздоганяючи вживання цього слова. Натомість в універсальних словниках нічого не змінилося. Зокрема, Великий тлумачний словник української мови за ред. Бусла (2005) наголошує а.

Answer (score 7):

+1: Київський Універ, кібер, ніхто інакше як "визначни́к" й не казав.

Гіпотеза: якщо термінологію позичали з інших слов'янських мов, то "визна́чник" могли перетягнути з польського "wyznacznik" разом з тамтешнім обов'язковим наголосом на передостанньому складі.
Не пригадаю, аби взагалі використовувався термін "визна́чний", але як би використовувався, то звучав би накшталт "визна́чуваний". Здаєсь, і це потягнули з польської "wyznaczony" чи "wyznaczny". Хоч, поправді, і "визна́чуваний" схожий на аналог "wyznaczony".